# move each images with same class name through a spiral path one after the other using jquery

Tags: jquery

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/arfMb.png)

```js
var t = 0;
var k=0;
function moveit() {
    t += 0.05;
k=k+.001;
    var r = 100;
    var xcenter = 100;
    var ycenter = 100;
    var newLeft = Math.floor(xcenter + (r*k * Math.cos(t)));
    var newTop = Math.floor(ycenter + (r *k* Math.sin(t)));
    $('.poss img').each(function(){$(this).animate({
        top: newTop,
        left: newLeft,
    }, 1, function() {
        moveit();
    });
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    moveit();
});
```

```css
.poss{
  position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
top: 90px;
}

.poss img {
position: absolute;
border-radius: 80px;
border: 2px solid white;
box-shadow: 2px 2px 14px rgba(30, 38, 74, 0.86);

 -moz-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-drag: none;
  user-drag: none;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- comt -->   
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href='/stylesheets/style.css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<%= baseUrl %>/stylesheets/bootstrap.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<%= baseUrl %>/javascripts/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>

    <script src="<%= baseUrl %>/javascripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<%= baseUrl %>javascripts/appscript.js"></script>

    <style>
    .carousel-inner > .item > img,
    .carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
        width: 70%;
        margin: auto;
    }
    </style>

</head>

<body background="<%= baseUrl %>images/back.jpg">
<!-- navigator -->

 

<div class="poss" style=" float: none; z-index: 1000; position: absolute; width: 20%; margin: 0 auto; left: 0px; right: 0px; "  >
<div class="poss" style=" float: none; z-index: 1000; position: absolute; width: 20%; margin: 0 auto; left: 0px; right: 0px; "  ><div class="poss" style=" float: none; z-index: 1000; position: absolute; width: 20%; margin: 0 auto; left: 0px; right: 0px; "  ><div class="poss" style=" float: none; z-index: 1000; position: absolute; width: 20%; margin: 0 auto; left: 0px; right: 0px; "  ><div class="poss" style=" float: none; z-index: 1000; position: absolute; width: 20%; margin: 0 auto; left: 0px; right: 0px; "  >
  
  
  
</body>

</html>
```

In the above attached code all images with class "poss" are following the spiral path together. I want each images start animating from center, follow the spiral one after the other and animation will stop when the images gone to its places in the spiral.

Comment: help me to find solution for the above code. please..

Answer (score 0):

First create a list of images to animate. This can be done by simply define a global Array and push all image objects into it (Version A)

```
var allImages = new Array();
function initAnimation(){
  $('.poss img').each(dunction(i,e){
    allImages.push(e);
  });
}
```

or by adding a attribute to all and select them later by atribute  (Version B)

```
function initAnimation(){
  $('.poss img').attr('notAnimatedYet', true);
}
```

Second step is to define a function to move the image. And animate only the first image. When this animation is done take the next one.

```
var t = 0;
var k=0;
function moveit() {
    t += 0.05;
    k=k+.001;
    var r = 100;
    var xcenter = 100;
    var ycenter = 100;
    var newLeft = Math.floor(xcenter + (r*k * Math.cos(t)));
    var newTop = Math.floor(ycenter + (r *k* Math.sin(t)));
    var element;

    // Begin for Version A
    if(allImages.length == 0){
      return;
    }
    element = allImages.ushift();
    // End of Version A

    // Begin for Version B
    if($('.poss img[notAnimatedYet=true]')).length == 0){
      return;
    }
    element = $('.poss img[notAnimatedYet=true]')[0];
    $(element).attr('notAnimatedYet', false);
    // End of Version B


    $(element).animate({
        top: newTop,
        left: newLeft,
    }, 1, function() {
        moveit();
    });
  });
}
```